# Read current max multipartfile size

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file-io, properties

I want to verify the max permitted size for `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile` for my current spring boot application. But I can't seem to find it. I'm using Spring boot `2.2.4.RELEASE`. I've tried like this:

```
@Autowired
Environment env;
....
    System.out.println(env.getProperty("spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size"));
    System.out.println(env.getProperty("servlet.multipart.max-file-size"));
    System.out.println(env.getProperty("multipart.max-file-size"));
    System.out.println(env.getProperty("multipart.maxFileSize");
....
```

But all I get are nulls

**EDIT:**
If I explicitly set `spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size`, in the `application.properties` file, I can read its String, however I want to check for the max-file-size even if not explicitly set. Preferably in bytes.

Comment: Try uploading a 5/10gb file. The exception will tell you what is the max size possible. You want to log that size in your application?

Comment: I want to be able to give feedback to the user about the max size. Regardless if it is explicitly set or not

Comment: I think `1 MB`.

Comment: Yes it is 1MB or 1048576 bytes, but the question is not, "what is the default limit?", but "how can you read said limit?". `Through an exception` is not a real answer

Comment: Check the source code then.